# How to call a function whose definition arguement is empty?

Tags: c++

I actually came across this when I was given a definition for a function and was required to compile it. Say, it went like this:

```
double SumSeries ()
{
    ........................
    return sum;
}
```

The body is the required code to print the value of a given series of numbers. In the main function, how will I call this function and then print the return value?

Comment: @Aneek..If the method is calculating the sum of numbers in an array, you need to pass array as argument to this function . However, if the method is just printing the sum, no need to pass any argument to this function. You can calculate the sum of numbers in an array outside and store it in sum variable. Plz let me know the exact method implementation so that I can be able to help.

Comment: brush your basics brother

Answer (score 0):

You call functions like that: `SomeFunc(someParams);` but when there are *no arguments to pass to that function*, you just *don't pass any*!

```
double ret = YourFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
 std::cout << "Result : " << SumSeries() << '\n';
}
```

Assuming function has code for sum.

Comment: I hope it works. So after this, I then type the definition of the function, right? Will let you know, once I compiled it!

Comment: Is it necessary to use void in the main function? Is there any reason behind not using int?

Comment: void is used when we don't want to return any thing and nothing else, you can use int so at the end you have to return an integer which will be used by os or calling function. You can define your function after this but it would be better to declare it before main like this `double SumSeries();`

Comment: @Aneek - `int` is required by the language definition. Some compilers allow `void`, but that's a (bad) extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout<<SumSeries();
```

To call a function with empty arguments: NameOfFunction();
If it return something then save the value in a variable or print out.

Comment: So here, the variable sum is returned in the definition. So, how I use it in main function?

Comment: void main()//or int
    {
        .......//your other stuff
        cout<<SumSeries();
    }
If the function SumSeries is above the main function,if not then you must create a prototye for function above the main like this: double SumSeries();